# Adding "db_executor" role for multiple roles in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

When i grant permission to add role db_executor for multiple users(d2mgr,d2user) when creating a new database i am getting db_executor role added only for single user(d2user) and what is the solution for adding to other user also,please suggest me with some relevant answers

Comment: What SQL did you use please?

Answer (score 0):

```
exec sp_addrolemember @membername = 'd2mgr', @rolename = 'db_executor'
exec sp_addrolemember @membername = 'd2user', @rolename = 'db_executor'
```